# Change parskip in beamer without side effects

Tags: beamer, spacing, parskip

**Background**

If I understand correctly, `beamer` does not distinguish between lines and paragraphs, as far a vertical spacing is concerned. As an example, there is no visible difference in this MWE:

[image]

```
\documentclass[t]{beamer}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}{Two Paragraphs}
Text

Text
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}{One Paragraph}
Text\\
Text
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

I would like to have a distinction, though, and I thought I could just set `\parskip` to some desired value. However, it turns out that this leads to other undesired side effects. For example, columns move up:

[image]

```
\documentclass[t]{beamer}
\setlength{\parskip}{5pt}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}{No Columns}
Text
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}{Columns}
    \begin{columns}[t,onlytextwidth]
    \column{0.5\textwidth}
        Text
    \end{columns}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

**Question**

How can I realize a global custom parskip (or something equivalent that allows to distinguish between lines and paragraphs) without side effects? There is no need to make it adjustable throughout the document. Setting it once at the beginning would be enough.

**EDIT:** Replaced `\par` with blank line in first MWE